# TFS equivalent of "svn info"?

Tags: command-line, tfs

How can I determine the current change set version that a local work folder has using the TFS command line clients? I dont want to check what the latest version on the server but how "old" a local work folder is.

["svn info"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re13.html) will print information about paths in your working copy, ie, revision and other info.

Answer (score 2):

Im answering my own question as I just found the answer. Using the [**properties**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzy14b58.aspx) command did the trick.

```
tf properties .
```

would output information (when run in the active work folder) such as this:

```
Local information:
  Local path:  /codeplex/workspace
  Server path: $/project
  Changeset:   1327
  Change:      none
  Type:        Folder
Server information:
  Server path:   $/project
  Changeset:     1327
  Deletion ID:   0
  Lock:          none
  Lock owner:    null
  Last modified: 2010-sep-22 00:13:58
  Type:          Folder
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>> tf info {file or directory name}
```